# The text box in asp.net is not updating it's Text

Tags: asp.net

'm working on an asp.net assignment, where i have to display profile information to the user and also have to edit it if the user wants to edit it.

now, my problem is:

I'm able to show the profile info to the user but while editing it (I 'm using same text box for editing profile information) 'm getting the previous value of the text in the same text box i.e the one which is coming from my Database. the text in the text box is not getting replaced even if i have replaced it with the new Text.

in below code the `txtEditName` is getting its value from database.and I want to edit on click event of `btnSaveChanges` but when i debug the code i came to know that the value persists which is coming from database.

my test box is :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditName" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="25px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my aspx.cs code is :

```
BALSuperAdminProfile objSuperAdminProfile = new BALSuperAdminProfile();
DataTable dt;
int sa_id = 1;

void showSuperAdminInfo()
     {
          try
           {
               dt = objSuperAdminProfile.getSuperAdminProfileDetails(sa_id);

               txtEditName.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
           }
         catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    lblResult.Text = "Could Not load Database. Please try Again latter.";
                }
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                showSuperAdminInfo();
            }

            protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string name=txtEditName.Text;
                try
                {
    dt = objSuperAdminProfile.editSuperAdminProfile(sa_id, name,);
                    lblResult.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    showSuperAdminInfo();
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    lblResult.Text = Ex.Message;
                }

            }

            protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
            {
                txtEditName.Enabled = true;       
            }
        }
```

what could be the problem?

Please Help.

Comment: Show the code you tried. Includes a text box handling in a page life cycle

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditName" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="25px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox> 

this is the code 'm using for Text Box in aspx page 

will be uploading the code for .cs page asap

Comment: also 'm retrieving the information of user from database on PAGE LOAD event.

Comment: @Girish Please update your question itself instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showSuperAdminInfo();
        }

 protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name=txtEditName.Text;
           try
            {
                dt = objSuperAdminProfile.editSuperAdminProfile(name);
                lblResult.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                showSuperAdminInfo();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                lblResult.Text = Ex.Message;
            }

        }

Answer (score 0):

Write Your Retrieve Code on

```
If(!isPostBack)
{
}
```

at page load make that textbox  property ReadOnly:True

when you click on edit button make Readonly to false and write the code for updating

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {  if(!isPostBack){
                showSuperAdminInfo();}
            }

Comment: Welcum @girish.. please accept the answer,because viewers easily find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

While displaying the name in text box you are using the row[0][0] element in showSuperAdminInfo()

```
txtEditName.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
```

Where as while displaying the result in label you are using a different index in btnSaveChanges_Click()

```
lblResult.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Another thing to check is your function editSuperAdminProfile() in your business layer.

Comment: in my database Rows[0][0].tostring will show superAdminId.
but i want to display and edit name which is 3rd column, so need to use Rows[0][2].ToString.

but problem is not because of that. i 'm not getting the updated text in the text box txtEditName this text box is actually preserving it's values which are there at page load event.

Comment: try
{
objbid.Connection.Open();
objTrans = objbid.Connection.BeginTransaction();
objbid.Transaction = objTrans;
dt = objComnCls.LINQToDataTable(objbid.SP_EditSuperAdmin(sa_id, name).ToList());
objTrans.Commit();
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
objTrans.Rollback();
}
finally
{
objbid.Connection.Close();
}
return dt;